# iOS developer build does not install on one iphone 4S

Tags: ios

I have a developer build, made using iOS 6 library, targeting iOS 4+ devices, and it installs and runs on 4 different iphones, and 2 ipads. But for some reason, on one of the iPhones 4S with iOS 5.1.1, the app starts installing and get stuck at about 50% of the progress bar.
The carrier is Verizon, the phone has been bought this year.

Anyone has any insight?

Answer (score 0):

The UDID of the device might not be present in the provisioning profile you signed with.

Comment: it would not let you drop the build file to the phone if that were the case.

Comment: Actually it does, I have seen some cases where that has happened and after 50%-75% it stops saying it could not download. I would suggest going to your oraganizer. Re-download your Prov profile and sign it. Try it

Comment: One last try from my side. Open up the device in organizer. Remove the profile from there. Download the profile from Apple Developer and copy this one to that phone. If this gets copied, then try and build it. If the above provisioning profile is copied and the app has started downloading then it means the errors are at some place else

Answer (score 0):

I suggest watching the Device Console in the XCode Organizer screen.  You'll be able to see any error messages during the install and determine what the issue is.  You can watch the console even if you're installing via TestFlight or some other mechansism.

If the device is thousands of miles away :) then you can have the user collect the console logs for you via the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465).  [Per Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html):

> Getting Console Output Without Xcode Sometimes you may have to debug a
>   problem "in the field", or tell a tester how to gather more
>   information and send it to you. When installing Xcode isn't an option,
>   download the iPhone Configuration Utility to save Console output. It
>   is available for both Mac OS X and Windows.
>
> 1) Plug in the device and open iPhone Configuration Utility
>
> 2) Select the device under DEVICES in the left-hand column
>
> 3) Select the Console tab
>
> 4) Press the "Save Console As..." button in the lower right of the
>   window to export the Console log.

Comment: The device is physically thousand miles away from the computer that created the build and cannot be directly connected to XCode. I do like the idea though.

Comment: I updated my answer to include information for this scenario.